# Cannot subscript a value of type NSDictionary with an index of type String. While converting from Swift 2.3 -> 3.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3.2

I need Help. While conversion from Swift 2.3 -> 3.2 I received below error. I'm not able to resolve this error.

Below is my coding stuff, where I'm facing some issues.

Error :

> Cannot subscript a value of type NSDictionary with an index of type String

At this line : `if let tempValue:AnyObject = tempDict["value"]  {`

```
if (productToReturn.planoRetailPackSize == nil || productToReturn.planoRetailPackSize == "0.0") {
            if let dataToProcess:NSDictionary = dict["data"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let productDataRecord:NSDictionary = dataToProcess["productDataRecord"] as? NSDictionary{
                        if let module:NSArray = productDataRecord["module"] as? NSArray{
                            for (_,value) in module.enumerated(){
                                if let parentDic:NSDictionary = value as? NSDictionary{
                                    if let cpmChild:NSDictionary = parentDic["cem:canadaExtensionModule"] as? NSDictionary {
                                        if let tempDict:NSDictionary = cpmChild["retailPackSize"] as? NSDictionary {
                                                if let tempValue:AnyObject = tempDict["value"]  { //Error is Here
                                                let myValue: String = String(describing: tempValue)
                                                productToReturn.planoRetailPackSize = myValue
                                    }
                                }//item
                            }
                        }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me. I'm very new to iOS. Not able to understand this type of error.

Comment: Don't use NS classes in Swift such as NSDictionary. Use a `Dictionary` or `[String: Any]`

Comment: ... and don't annotate types the compiler can infer.

Comment: @vadian plz can you help me...I'm not able to solve it.

Comment: What (static) type is `tempValue` supposed to be? Certainly **not** `AnyObject`

Comment: Plz check now my updated Quest. I've pasted all code

Comment: Hope it will help you to predict proper way to solve my query.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. What is the expected type of `tempValue`? A `String`, an `Int` or what?

Comment: It's a String type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use native types

```
if let dataToProcess = dict["data"] as? [String:Any],
    let productDataRecord = dataToProcess["productDataRecord"] as? [String:Any],
    let module = productDataRecord["module"] as? [[String:Any]] {
    for value in module {
        if let cpmChild = value["cem:canadaExtensionModule"] as? [String:Any],
            let tempDict = cpmChild["retailPackSize"] as? [String:Any],
            let myValue = tempDict["value"] as? String {
            productToReturn.planoRetailPackSize = myValue
        }
    }
}
```

Note : In the `for` loop `myValue` will overwrite `planoRetailPackSize` in each iteration. This is most likely not intended.

Comment: Hi @vadian can you please help me out in this Question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50855040/9940506

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to use native Swift types.  The alternative is to cast your subscripts to `NSString`.

```
...
if let tempValue:AnyObject = tempDict["value" as NSString]  {
...
```